# Change img src attribute on hover for multiple img tags

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I wonder if anyone can help!? It's been a while since I've been on here so hope somebody can give me some pointers as I have hit a mental block!

I'm trying to change the src attribute for an image on hover which might not sound too difficult but I'm trying to do it for a number of components and write a function that will take care of them all at once so I don't have to repeat code!

I have done a fair bit of digging and in my head, this seems to make the most sense but it's not working! Can anyone see where I'm going wrong??

```js
$(function(){
    $('img.natcard-img').each(function() {
        var image=$('img',this),
            offPng=image.attr('src'),
            onPng=offPng.replace(/-one\.(\w+)$/,'-two.$1');
            onImg=new Image();
        onImg.src=onPng;
        $(this).hover(
            function(){image.attr('src',onPng)},
            function(){image.attr('src',offPng)}
        )
    });
    
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<img src="https://via.placeholder.com/140x100" alt="example 1" class="natcard-img">
```

From above, I'm using a naming convention for the images that should make it an easier swap ie. just amend the filename slightly in each case and I believe this should work on any file type jpg/png.

Many thanks for any pointers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tested it on my computer. In the console I had this error:

```
jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js:2 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'replace' of undefined
```

I solved it by fixing the selector, replacing:

```js
var image=$('img',this),
```

With this:

```js
var image=$(this),
```

Inside `$(...).each(function() { ... })`, `this` is a DOM node, and you just need to wrap it with `$()` to get a jQuery object.

Comment: Thanks Benito! This makes perfect sense (no pun intended!) but still no joy! As per my comment above I've tested on multiple browsers...may have to come back at it with freash eyes in the morning!

Comment: Do you mean it didn't work with _any_ browser? Strange! Could you open the console and give us whatever you might find here? Fresh eyes should help anyway ;). Good luck!

Comment: Gimme a sec - I've just had my live server fail on me so potentially it might have been bugging out on me! Yeah - that code wasn't working in Chrome, firefox or edge. I'm going to fire it up again and see if we have lift off! If I get anything in the console that might help I'll shout!! ;)

Comment: Guess what? It's working! ;) Thank so much for the help - I can fall asleep without head scratching now!

Comment: Glad to contribute to a better sleep!

Answer (score 0):

Just change `var image=$('img',this)` to:

```
var image=$(this)
```

What yours is doing is looking for an img that is a child of the current one ...which is not a real scenario

Comment: Thanks charlietfl - that makes perfect sense and I could have kicked myself when I saw that! I've now changed it but still not seeing the image change on hover...tested on multiple browsers aswell!

Comment: Do images show up on page load? In other words initial path is correct?

Comment: yep but guess what?! After my live server and laptop freaked out and I shut down and started again...it's working fine!!! I'd have been going round in circles...Thank you so much for the help - really appreciate it. :)